# How do i make connection of MySQL database in Spark-streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I can connect Mysql database in case pf JdbcRDD and DataFrames. But, How to make connection of MySQL database in  Spark-streaming ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read from the MySQL table then you need to create a CustomReceiver for it with your requirement.

[Custom Receivers](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-custom-receivers.html)

You can also write the Scala or Java code for the same.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In custom receiver logic, i have created database connection but i am confused, in which form (jdbcrdd or DF) i can retrieve the table so i can use this in spark-streaming? Basically i need join between 2 tables in spark.

Comment: Well that is your business requirement, You can modify your custom receiver as per your needs. Keeping the best practices in mind and not to write the whole code in the Receiver itself :)